# Attribute presence generic check

Tags: c++, c++11, bit-manipulation, c++14

My requirement is to parse on XML and populate an object. How do I automatically track if attribute xyz is present once the object is populated from the Xml. Please note that I will no longer have access to the parsed buffer after the object is populated. Hence I need some mechanism to know whether the attribute was present in XML and the same is populated in the object.

I have the below solution in my mind but not sure if anything more efficient possible. Also I am looking for a generic solution for this problem.

- define a bit for each of the attribute in a class.
- setter function should set that bit while parsing XML when attribute is present
- getter function should check the bit before returning the attribute value by reference argument . It should return false when bit is not set. ( The getter function return type should be boolean and it accepts one argument which is of type attribute and populate it when present)

Comment: The last bullet implies that you can return false OR return an attribute by reference. Let's get a little more concrete and say it should return an `optional`

Comment: You say you need to track the existence of an attribute, but you want to return a reference to it if it exists. A data structure that only holds the existence of the attributes is therefore insufficient. Why do you need to track if the attribute is in the XML when you can make query the object for that information?

Comment: @andyg updated the statement accordingly.

Comment: Regarding your edit: is anyone forcing this interface on you? It is a way inferior way to `optional`. If you have the choice, it is better to redesign the class interface.

Comment: I need to check the presence of an attribute before I could use it. And obviously I don't want to keep the Xml parser for program lifetime. Any better design solution would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment I gather that you *can* change the design, so this is what I would do:

Replace all optional members with the aptly-named `std::optional` or the boost equivalent if the former is not available.

```
using std::optional;    // facilitates easy switching between std and boost if needed

class MyClass {
    optional<int> some_value;
    // Similarly for rest of attributes

    void set_some_value(int value_to_store) { some_value = value_to_store; }

    optional<int> get_some_value() { return some_value; }
}
```

To read from it do as follows

```
MyClass instance;
// ... parse XML and set attributes
auto some_value = instance.get_some_value;
if (some_value) {
    do_something_with_int(*some_value);
}
```

Some notes on `optional`:

- Default-constructed `optional`s are empty. This means that every attribute you don't explicitly set is empty by default.
- Dereferencing an empty optional is undefined behavior. There are safer ways to access it. In this example it is safe because we manually checked for it since I assume you'd like to branch on the existence of your attribute anyway.
- The managed object is guaranteed to be inside the allocated `optional` object. This means no dynamic allocation which is great for speed. If you have any huge objects, however, this can cause stack overflow issues. It's not likely, though, as most real world scenarios of large objects are using a `string` or some STL container/wrapper that holds its data on the heap anyway.
- I couldn't find a mention of the space cost in the standard. I believe it is typically implemented with a single `bool` inside every optional object. `sizeof(bool)` is often `sizeof(int)`. This makes it more space consuming than necessary, but it's as fast as possible. This is generally a good trade-off, but if you encounter memory usage problems and you have a lot of objects holding `optional`s you might need to find a more space-optimal solution. If you can use sentinel values to signal non-existence, look up implementations of compact optional objects.

Comment: The solution looks cool but unfortunately std::optional is c++17 utility and we are using c++11 at the moment and I am not seeing any  upgrade to c++17 very soon

Comment: Then change the first line to `using boost::optional`. If that is also not an option, write your own optional class that implements the same interface.

Comment: how does changing the first line would work? Could you please explain? Is std optional available in c++11 as well?

Comment: My bad, I assumed you'd be familiar with the boost library. In short it is an extensive experimental C++ library. Most standard C++ features have been first implemented and tried out in boost; `optional` is no exception. Download boost and include the appropriate header file to use `boost::optional` in older C++ versions.

Comment: Thanks. Any specific reason u find this solution better than what I have proposed? Bit manipulation will always be faster and efficient though we are giving some space for manual mistakes while writing setters and getters.

Comment: Bits will be more space-efficient but they will be slower on every platform that I'm aware of. The processor does not work with bits. Forcing it to do so will actually incur extra costs of bit-masking for every read/write operation. You should trust the compiler to choose the appropriate size rather than force it to use bits, unless you have severe memory restrictions and at least tens of millions of `bool`s.